# Will javafxports android still work with the new android studio?

Tags: android, javafx, android-studio, build-error

I got the error "Error: Can't build Android. Path to Android SDK was not set or is invalid!" and I'm using the new android studio so I was wondering if javafxports android works with the new android studio?
My current path the the android sdk is:

```
     C:\Users\svond_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Comment: javafxports have a [support group](http://www.javafxports.org/page/Support), probably best to ask this question there.

Comment: Thanks I will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm currently using Intellij. It works very well. There is a community edition of intellij. Since basicly Android Studio and Intellij are built from the same source code. The gradle plugins works very well on Intellij.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/

Regards,

Ivan